# How to arrange inference rules in a figure so that they are as tight as possible?

Tags: bussproofs

I am wondering how people manage to arrange their inference rules so that it's not only  enjoyable to look at but also very compact. For instance, when I use `bussproofs` and the following trees:

```
\begin{prooftree}
  \AxiomC{}
  \UnaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash T <: \top$}
\end{prooftree}

\begin{prooftree}
  \AxiomC{}
  \UnaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash \bot <: T$}
\end{prooftree}

\begin{prooftree}
  \AxiomC{}
  \UnaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash T <: T$}
\end{prooftree}
```

The current way I do it is by using `multicols` and manually arrange their alignment. But this is not very satisfactory, and if I change the layout of the article, then I will have to go through all the figures containing inference rules and rearrange them again.

Is there a good way for you to improve the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not use the `prooftree` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1][1-5]
\begin{equation*}
  \AxiomC{}
  \UnaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash T <: \top$}
  \DisplayProof
\qquad
  \AxiomC{}
  \UnaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash \bot <: T$}
  \DisplayProof
\qquad
  \AxiomC{}
  \UnaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash T <: T$}
  \DisplayProof
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The `bussproofs` command are flushed when `\DisplayProof` is found and a box is formed.

[image]

Comment: what??? wow, it does seem that I've spent lots of time on unnecessary effort!

Comment: @JasonHu Section 2.2 of the manual. :-)